# How to loop audio in soundmanger2

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

How can we loop the same audio file in soundamanager2 ??

this is my sample code

```
function playSound(url) {
            soundManager.setup({
            url: 'swf',
            onready: function() {
                 soundManager.createSound({
                 id: 'samplesound',
                 url: url,
                 volume: 100
                 });
                 soundManager.play('samplesound');
                 }
            }); 
        }
```

calling it from a tag like

```
<a href='javascrit:void(0);' onclick='playSound('url');'></a>
```

can anyone guide me to loop this sound continuously for respective times ??

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop the sound using the play command

The following should play the sound 3 times

```
soundManager.play('samplesound',{loops: 3});
```

a hack to get the loops working could be

```
var loops = 3;
var looped = 0;
    soundManager.createSound({
                     id: 'samplesound',
                     url: url,
                     volume: 100,
                      onfinish:function() { 
                         if(looped<loops){
                             soundManager.play('samplesound'); 
                             looped++; 
                          } else{   
                             looped = 0;
                          }
                      )}
                     });
```

see

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/

and

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsoundmethods

Comment: @luvboy  does it play at all?  what errors are your getting in the error console?

Comment: i tried infinite loop, which is working...but how can i stop the sounds say after 3 or 4 times ??

Comment: and i'm not getting any errors if i add loops, but somehow it is not at all playing the sound

Comment: Amazing, i really don't know we can do the logics in function()...thanks for the tip

Comment: and finally, is there a way we can change the speed of the sound Tucker...i'm actually developing a card game and want to add some sounds

Comment: i don't know how to adjust play speed using sound manager 2 sorry

Answer (score 1):

To set the default option at "loop:1" will play each sound just once. In my site,Loop: 2 would play it over and over. On their demo page, they loop it "loops: 3"

soundManager.defaultOptions = {

```
 loops: 2

};
```

Comment: It does say on their site that html5 has an endless loop problem and a manual work around is required: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/#looping-conventional

Answer (score 1):

Use this utility function:

```
function loopSound(sound, times) {
    var current = 0;
    _loopSound(sound, times, current);
    function _loopSound(sound, times, current) {
        if (++current <= times) {
            sound.play({
                onfinish : function() {
                    _loopSound(sound, times, current);
                }
            }); 
        }
    }   
}

var mySound= soundManager.createSound({
              url: '/mySound.mp3'
            });
loopSound(mySound, 3);
```

Comment: I dont think this would stop looping if you stopped the file from playing using .stop() or .pause(), correct?

Comment: @babycakes You should check but I believe it won't because the loop will keep calling play() N times recursively.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`soundManager.play('mysound', { loops: Infinity });`